# Can we extract a specific alias from a java.security.KeyStore object with its keypair and cert, then inject into a new java.security.KeyStore object?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I am reading a KeyStore and want to extract the details with respect to specific alias. I am needing a KeyStore object to feed to KeyManagerFactory while using init method

```
kmf.init(<OldKeyStoreObject>,<keyStorePwdCharArray>)
```

But this  for now contains multiple alias.

I want to get the Private key and cert of specific the alias extracted and store it into specific variables.

Now what if I create a new KeyStore object(which is empty), Then inject the 
private key and cert store earlier.

Do I need to give the details of Organization and other stuff when we create a keyStore using KeyTool, If yes the how to do the same in java code.

Finally I want to do is,

```
kmf.init(<NewKeyStoreObjectWhichHasInjectedAliasFromOld>,<keyStorePwdCharArray>)
```

Which will be having only one alias which i injected.

So how to create this

Refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry(java.lang.String,%20java.security.Key,%20char[],%20java.security.cert.Certificate[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now what if I create a new KeyStore object(which is empty), Then inject the private key and cert store earlier.

Yes, you can do this.

```
KeyStore one = KeyStore.getInstance(your_ks_type); // optionally add ,provider
try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename)){ one.load(is,pw); }
// or other input source like JAR, server, whatever
PrivateKey privkey = (PrivateKey) one.getKey (alias,pw);
// keypass is _usually_ same as storepass but may differ for some keystores like JKS 
Certificate[] chain one.getCertificateChain (alias);
// use java.security.cert.Certificate, not the obsolete java.security.Certificate 

KeyStore two = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); // any filebased type (and optionally provider)
// doesn't matter which since we don't read or write it
two.load(null); // dummy call makes it ready to use
two.setKeyEntry (dummyalias, privkey, pwx, chain);
// two now contains (in memory only) the single privateKey entry
```

Alternatively, if you are really creating an SSLContext, you don't really need a KeyManager *Factory* or even the standard but hidden [Sun]X509KeyManagerImpl it creates, 
but only *a* X509KeyManager instance that JSSE can call, you can do that directly:

```
// get privkey and chain from keystore to local variables as above
// below Java 8 must declare them final (after that it's implicit) 
one = null; // so _not_ effectively captured

KeyManager km = new X509ExtendedKeyManager (){
  // anonymous (local) class captures privkey and chain variables from containing method
  public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias){ return (X509Certificate[]) chain; }
  // KeyStore API is declared using abstract java.security.cert.Certificate but implementations 
  // actually use specific java.security.cert.X509Certificate or a subclass so cast works
  public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias){ return privkey; }
  public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers){ return new String[]{"dummy"}; }
  public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers){ return new String[]{"dummy"}; }
  // at least one of these depending how this (context and) keymanager will be used:
  public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket){ return "dummy"; }
  public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket){ return "dummy"; }
  public String chooseEngineClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine){ return "dummy"; }
  public String chooseEngineServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine){ return "dummy"; }
};
```

> Do I need to give the details of Organization and other stuff when we create a keyStore using KeyTool, If yes the how to do the same in java code.

I think you may be confusing creating a *keypair* (or privatekey) and creating a *keystore*.

When you use keytool to generate (create) a keypair, it also creates a dummy selfsigned (X.509) certificate,
and that certificate is supposed to identify the person or entity owning it (and the matching privatekey).
That identity is represented in a form called DistinguishedName, which has several possible fields (or formally 
in the ASN.1 defined by X.500, Attribute Value Assertions), including country, state or province, city or locality, 
organization, organizational unit, and common name (which keytool prompts somewhat misleadingly as "first and last name").
What identity info is actually needed in this cert, for example whether the organization field needs to 
be filled at all and if so with what, depends on (1) whether you are going to actually use the dummy cert, 
or replace it with a 'real' cert obtained from a CA (Certificate Authority), and if so which CA using what request procedure, 
and (2) what you will use the resulting cert (either dummy or real) for -- HTTPS, other SSL/TLS, email, document signing and/or encryption, code signing, etc.
-- in short, a lot more info than you provided in your question.

It is fairly common to use `keytool -genkeypair` on a new keystore, in which case 
you create the keypair and dummy cert (including identity info) *and* keystore together. 
But it is entirely possible to create a keypair and dummy cert in an existing keystore, 
in which case you do supply the certificate identity info (and don't create the keystore),
or to create a keystore (for use as truststore) without creating a keypair and dummy cert, 
in which case you don't supply certificate identity info.

Comment: Why is it like chooseClientAlias  chooseServerAlias, I mean why Client and Server and not just chooseAlias ? When we create a KeyStore using KeyTool we don't specify such things right ? Why is alias, Client or Server dependent here. ?

Comment: And also, do we need to have `@Override` before each method in X509ExtendedKeyManager ?

Comment: (1) choose{}Alias is a function of the KeyManager, during a handshake, in which keytool is not involved. keytool does allow you to specify the alias of a new entry (or change an existing one), and that alias name (or those names) are what KeyManager normally 'chooses' and tells JSSE to use. For TLS<=1.2 the information available to the server and the client when choosing what key&cert to use is different -- notice the different type of the first argument. TLS1.3 in 2018 changed this, but the API was designed about 17 years earlier, apparently without hiring precognitives or time travellers.

Comment: (2) You don't _need_ `@Override`; Java was initially defined without it and it's optional, although if you make a mistake it will give you a quick, specific diagnostic rather than 'mysteriously' dispatching in a way you didn't expect. Your choice.

Comment: Also am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.security.cert.Certificate; cannot be cast to [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate`. I guess that cast doesn't work.

Comment: Changed the getCertificateChain method to:`public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias){ //return chain; 
           X509Certificate certArr[] = new X509Certificate[chain.length];
           for(int i=0;i<chain.length ;i++){
            certArr[i] = (X509Certificate) chain[i];
           }
           return certArr;
           }`

Comment: In my case, the type is TLsV1.2 , but the overriding methods chooseEngineClientAlias & chooseClientAlias are not being executed ! I have log statements in them to verify. So cert is not being passed at all which results in fatal alert: handshake_failure. Why overriding methods are not being executed ?

Comment: @Ankit: impossible to say with so little info. If you can create a 'minimal' (at least small) reproducible example, and you don't discover the answer yourself in the process , post a question about it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you for reply. I was able to fixed it. I have to change client library from httpcore to httpclient !

https://www.naschenweng.info/2018/02/01/java-mutual-ssl-authentication-2-way-ssl-authentication/

Comment: Interesting observation is , I am calling WS two ways, one using stand alone java program, Batch implementation which works fine with httpcore but second way when I tried using application somehow SSLContext was not initializing with the cert I wanted to load, actually it was not loading any cert ! Looks like some process was over riding it ! httpclient lib fixed it.